Craft 5.x: breaking out of a template with {% return %}
I’m building something in Craft 5 for the first time and it seems that breaking out of a template to print the output up to that point no longer works with the return statement.
For example:
<pre>{{ myVariable) }}</pre>
{% return %}

…generates:
Unknown "return" tag

I cannot find any documentation on this. What are we supposed to do instead?

The return tag is not native. You may have previously used the Twig Perversion plugin.

The dump() Twig function is useful for this (and slightly more convenient than adding those <pre> tags manually) e.g.
{{ dump(myVariable) }}
{% exit %}

Alternatively, there's the {% dd %} ("dump-and-die") tag, which will dump whatever variable you pass to it, and then terminate the request. Unlike the dump-and-exit approach it will not print the output up until its execution, though – only the thing being dumped.
{% dd myVariable %}


Looks like the answer is exit:
<pre>{{ myVariable) }}</pre>
{% exit %}

